# How to recover damaged video file on an External hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, video, external-hard-drive, filesystem-corruption

So I have a lot of video on an external HDD and most of the videos run fine. However, with some during the video it becomes very laggy and skips over some bits. When I have tried moving the files or zipping them, it said process failed because unable to read the video. Is there any way I could easily fix this on the videos. 
I am on OS X 10.11 and the Hard Drive in question is a 1TB LaCie PorscheDesign Hard drive.

Comment: I would start by checking the SMART stats for your disk to determine if it is healthy. hopefully the disk supports SMART: http://www.ehow.com/how_2091894_check-macs-smart-status.html . If the disk reports healthy, try a file system check: http://www.brighthub.com/computing/mac-platform/articles/2308.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds **very** much like your hard drive is dying.  You should get another similarly sized drive, a copy of Linux a Linux [rescue distro](http://www.bootmed.com/using-ddrescue-for-windows-machines/)  and use Gnu DDRescue to [bit] copy as much of the drive as possible.   (Start in forward direction till it gives errors, then reverse direction until you run out of time or get everything.

Comment: the disk is formatted to be read by OS X, so I do not believe it would be possible for it to be read on linux.

Comment: @karel I think I can do it. However, is there somewhere where I could find step by steps instructions on how to do it. I don't really want to risk messing it all up

Comment: @ThomasBraun, not only can linux mount HFS+, That doesn't matter, because DDRescue is a RAW imager and just reads/writes all the bits off the disk. it doesn't care what they are on any logical level like partition/filesystem type.

Comment: Mounting the filesystem does not help - you first need to get the data off the disk.

Comment: When you actually invoke DDRescue, I recommend you follow the methodology I describe here: http://superuser.com/questions/786488/ddrescue-did-i-do-the-wrong-command-which-is-causing-it-to-take-longer-then-ex . As for getting familiar with data recovery tasks and DDRescue, start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery . your first goal is to get a clean image (or clean enough) copied on to healthy media. After you have the image written out, try to mount it. if it fails, start with TestDisk, and then if its still unmountable, fall back on Photorec or other file carving utilities.

Comment: I have a tutorial for the Linux recovery. Maybe that helps ==> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/287439-emergency-kit-save-your-files-dead-os.html