# ddrescue slow when it copy the error blocks

Tags: ddrescue

I use the ddrescue to recover the data from the old hard disk, but I found it running very slow when it copy the failed blocks , can advise any options that can use on ddrescue to skip the error blocks or failed blocks , thanks !

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but (provided you use a log file), when reads start going slow, I find it useful to <crtl><c> the copy, then run it again with the "-r" switch so it starts copying from the end of the disk backward.

Comment: consider using a multi-pass approach: https://superuser.com/questions/786488/ddrescue-did-i-do-the-wrong-command-which-is-causing-it-to-take-longer-then-ex/786544#786544