# ddrescue 0% recovered - is the external hard drive dead?

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

I assume my external exFAT hard drive is dead. There are many questions about `ddrescue` but typically the poster manages to recover something. I just want an analysis of my results.

`ddrescue` shows:

[image: ddrescue results]

I have left it for longer than this before and the percentage rescued is always 0.00%

I also used TestDisk in Windows and that gave a "Read Error"

Sometimes I can `ls` the files and directories in the external hard drive; usually `ls` just hangs and never completes. I cannot copy the directories using `cp -r` for example as the copy process never gets past 0 bytes. But, clearly, Ubuntu (and Windows) can view the file structure. The problem is accessing the files and moving, copying, viewing them.

Any suggestions? There is almost 2TB of data which I would prefer not to lose but if the external drive is dead then it is dead.

Comment: how did you invoke ddrescue specifically?

Comment: It might be time to either consider the data lost or opt for a professional service.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I used: sudo ddrescue -d -f -r3 /dev/sda /dev/sdb log.txt where sda is the source (the external hard drive).

Comment: the disk is likely dead, but you may want to remove its enclosure, install it internally in your system, check it's SMART stats, and if it looks healthy, try again. I recommend a multipass process with ddrescue, like this: https://superuser.com/a/786544/171793